# How to save list by section except specific value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublist

I hope this question isn't a duplicate; Could not find the same problem.

I have following data lists

`data = ['0.112', '0.442', '-', '0.04', '0.41', '0.11', '0.7', '-', '-', '0.31', '0.9', '0.38', '0.22', '-']`

I want to store the data in the list by section except for a specific value '-' as follows.

`[['0.112', '0.442'],['0.04', '0.41', '0.11', '0.7'],['0.31', '0.9', '0.38', '0.22']]`

Comment: Are there other elements except numbers and '-'?

Comment: No, suppose there are only numbers and missing data(e.g. '-', 'NaN').

Comment: I developed a solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the job.

```
data = ['0.112', '0.442', '-', '0.04', '0.41', '0.11', '0.7', '-', '-', '0.31', '0.9', '0.38', '0.22', '-']
sublist = []
answer = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] == '-':
        answer.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
    else:
        sublist.append(data[i])
answer = [x for x in answer if x]
print(answer)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote this answer so that other people will be helped in the future.